# Writing a program using an indefinite loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, indefinite

The question I must complete is as follows;

After caffeine is absorbed into the body, 13% is eliminated from the body each
hour. Assume an 8-oz cup of brewed coffee contains 130 mg of caffeine and the
caffeine is absorbed immediately into the body. Write a program that allows the user to
enter the number of cups of coffee consumed. Write an indefinite loop (while) that
calculates the caffeine amounts in the body until the number drops to less than 65 mg

This is what I currently have

```
def main():
    cup = float(input("Enter number of cups of coffee:"))
    caff = cup * float(130)
    while caff <= 65:
        caff -= caff * float(0.13)

main()
```

The output must present a column with the amount of hours that have passed on the left and the remaining amount of caffeine on the right. I am looking for guidance as to where I should go from here. Thanks.

Comment: Just put a `print` in the loop that shows the current caffeine level.

Comment: The question is asked weirdly. What is the expected output? Amount of caffeine in the body at each and every second? How many time it takes to drop under 65mg? Etc.

Comment: `while caff <= 65:` should be `while caff >= 65:`

Comment: Also, saying it's an indefinite loop is pretty odd, because it's _not_ indefinite, it clearly terminates

Comment: If I attempt to print the variable caff within the loop, the program terminates after the input is given. Putting it outside the loop prints only the amount of caffeine in how ever many cups is entered into the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another variable counting the number of hours. Then just print the two variables in the loop.

You also need to invert the test in the `while`. You want to keep looping while the amount of caffeine is at least 65 mg.

```
def main():
    cup = float(input("Enter number of cups of coffee:"))
    caff = cup * float(130)
    hours = 0
    while caff >= 65:
        caff -= caff * float(0.13)
        hours += 1
        print(hours, caff)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the `while` loop and print the results.

```
def main():
cup = float(input("Enter number of cups of coffee:"))
caff = cup * float(130)
hours = 0
while caff >= 65:
    hours += 1
    caff -= caff * float(0.13)
    print("{0},{1}".format(hours, caff))
main()
```

Comment: Also, `caff -= caff * float(0.13)` can be re-rewritten more effectively as `caff *= float(0.87)`.